# Expo DevTools TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined

Tags: react-native, expo

I cannot get the Expo DevTools to work.
My approach:

```
npm install -g expo-cli
expo init
cd PROJECTNAME
expo start
```

I just get this error message in the console:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'compile' of undefined

And this one in the DevTools in the browser:

> Expo Developer Tools is disconnected from Expo CLI. Use the expo start
>   command to start the CLI again.

Does anyone know what Iam missing here?

Comment: I started getting this error today after upgrading expo-cli from 2.1.0 to latest. Reverting to 2.1.0 did not fix the error.

Comment: I'm getting the same error when running expo start.

Comment: I also got this error just now, I have two VMs in one of the VMs its working fine. To be further sure I made a new project by doing 'expo init' then expo start and it crashes for the new project as well.

Comment: Just filed a github issue with all the details: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/213

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This issue has now been solved. They just published expo-cli@2.4.1 and uninstalling and reinstalling makes it work:

```
npm uninstall -g expo-cli && npm i -g expo-cli
```

The issue was with a dependency of expo-cli 'joi' that was updated and broke stuff.

For more info: https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/213

Answer (score 2):

You aren't missing anything here - there appears to be a problem with this version of `expo-cli`.

The github thread shared in the comments has more information and a possible workaround. https://github.com/expo/expo-cli/issues/213

If the workaround doesn't work for you, I would suggest using `react-native-cli` or simply waiting a day or two until the expo team fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this issue changing the ExpoCli version.

Looking good with `expo-cli 2.2.5`. You can use it until they fix the issue with the latest version.

1. Uninstall expo-cli
2. `npm install -g expo-cli@2.2.5`

After starting project all looks good. 

`` There is a new version of expo-cli available (2.4.0).
You are currently using expo-cli 2.2.5
Run `npm install -g expo-cli` to get the latest version ``